# Prove that every $h \in \operatorname{span}\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has a unique representation $h=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k h_k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K}$ be Hilbert spaces, and let $\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{H},\left\{g_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence in $\mathcal{K}$. Assume that $\left\{g_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence with bound $B$, that $\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is complete in $\mathcal{H}$, and that there exists a constant $A>0$ such that
$$
A \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|c_k\right|^2 \leq\left\|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k h_k\right\|^2
$$
for all finite scalar sequences $\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$.

Prove that, if $A \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|c_k\right|^2 \leq\left\|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k h_k\right\|^2$, every $h \in \operatorname{span}\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has a unique representation $h=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k h_k$ with $\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ finite.

**My attempt**

If $h \in \operatorname{span}\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, then $h=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k h_k$. Thus, by assumption
$$\left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k h_k\right\|^2\geq A \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|c_k\right|^2$$
But how can I infer that $h \in \operatorname{span}\left\{h_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has a unique representation $h=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k h_k$?

Comment: By complete, do you mean orthonormal basis or just $\overline{\operatorname{span}(h_k:k\in\mathbb{N})}=\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Hi @OliverDíaz, no just span.

Comment: Mark, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4546937/121671) is another description of Bessel sequences that seems interesting. It uses duality.

Comment: @OliverDíaz thank you Oliver, it is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite sums one has that if
$$\sum^N_{n=1}c_n h_n = \sum^N_{n=1}b_n h_n$$
then $\sum^N_{n=1}(c_n-b_n)h_n=0$ and so, by assumption
$$A\sum^N_{n=1}|c_n-b_n|^2\leq \big\|\sum^N_{n=1}(c_n-b_n)h_n\big\|_H=\|0\|_H=0$$
Hence, $c_n=b_n$ for all $1\leq n\leq N$.